# \newgeometry at the beginning of section

Tags: titlesec, geometry

For some reasons, I would like to change the geometry at the beginning of each section, and later manually use `\restoregeometry`.
My first guess was to use `\titleformat` to force the execution of `\newgeometry` when a section begins.

The code is the following :

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{}{0pt}{\newgeometry{textwidth=5cm}} 

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\section{essai}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The section begins on a new page, so I think that in some sense, `\newgeometry` is executed, but has no effect on the text width. What am I doing wrong, and what would be the correct way  of doing so ?

Precision : in fact I do not want to do this for sections, but for a class of titles I manually define using `\titleclass`, but I don't think it makes a real difference.

Comment: do you want to change `\textwidth` just for section (or you titleclass) heading?

Comment: I really do want to change the whole geometry of the page and the following ones (in fact, the textwidth was just an example), and I want to do so at the beginning of each section, that's why I want this to be automatic.

Comment: do you want to start newpage with newgeometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\cspreto` from `etoolbox` to prepend `\newgeometry` to `\section`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{titlesec,etoolbox}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{}{0pt}{} 

\cspreto{section}{\newgeometry{textwidth=5cm}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\section{essai}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works just fine, thanks!  Any idea why my proposal didn't ?

Answer (score 0):

We can't use `\newgeometry`, `\restoregeometry` mipage.

Here is a solution useing `\titlepacing(*)` from titlesec package

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{titlesec}



\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{}{0pt}{}


\titlespacing*{\section}{-1cm}{2cm}{1cm}[10cm]

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\section{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{}{0pt}{} 
\let\mtsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{%
\newgeometry{textwidth=5cm}\mtsection}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\section{essai}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```